# What happens when a burrowing creature falls unconscious?

Tags: dnd-4e

What happens if a monster falls unconscious while burrowing?

My game just had an encounter where I launched into the boss with [Vestige of Baatar](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=11304) at the start of combat. On the boss's turn, it used a move action to burrow, but then failed its save at the end of its turn.

Our GM decided to have the monster surface so that we could simply murderdeathkill the thing, but I'd like to know what the rules have to say on the matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The creature would be stuck in it's burrow and suffocation rules would be in effect *if* necessary.

There is no specific rider for burrowing in the unconscious block and no specific effect from unconscious under either burrowing *or* tunneling. Thus the creature would stay in it's burrow, which is closed off at both ends and *might* start suffocating (if they stay down there for 3 minutes or take damage, and need to breathe).

However, there is no way for you to *follow* the creature down without starting to dig yourself. Burrows do not leave tunnels behind (in contrast to a tunneling speed).